# Xamarin "Attempting to JIT compile method error"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Hello in my project everthing is fine about Android but, if I try to build the project as a iOS project, I get this error

Attempting to JIT compile method 'MyApplication.App:InitializeComponent ()' while running in aot-only mode. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/ for more information.

How can I solve it? Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the project from my computer and I pulled the last push from git, then it worked.